# Satisfiability of the resolvent

Tags: logic

What would be a way to prove the following statement:

S = {$C_1$, $C_2$}
and C is the resolvent of $C_1$, $C_2$. By resolvent I mean the result of the resolution operation.

The theorem: if S is satisfiable, C is satisfiable too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is a *resolvent* of a set $S = \{ C_1, C_2 \}$ of two [clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) (where the clauses are disjunctions of literals or negated literals) ?

Suppose that the clauses $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjunctions with a literal $X$ occurring in $C_1$ and $\lnot X$ occurring in $C_2$.

The *resolvent* $C$ is obtained from $C_1$ and $C_2$ building a single disjunction from them, after deletion of all occurrences of $X$ and $\lnot X$.

If $S$ is *satisfiable*, we have a *valuation* $v$ such that $v(C_1)=v(C_2)=TRUE$; but clearly it is impossible thaa $v(X)=v(\lnot X)=TRUE$.

Assume that $v(X)=TRUE$; thus, there exists a literal or negated literal $Y$ in $C_2$ (obviously different from $X$) such that $v(Y)=TRUE$.

Thus, by the construction of $C$, $Y$ occurs in it and we have that : $v(C)=TRUE$, i.e. the resolvent $C$ is *satisfiable*.